# Transpiling seems to split a method apart

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, tsconfig

I am having a weird issue where the transpiler seems to split a single method into two parts:

Before transpiling:

```
MemberSchema.methods.addAccount = (account: IAccount): void => {
    this.account = new Account({
        ...account,
        isActive: true
    });

    bcrypt.genSalt(parseInt(process.env.SALT_WORK_FACTOR), function(err: Error, salt: any){
        if(err) throw err;

        bcrypt.hash(this.account.password, salt, null, function(err: Error, hash: any){
            if(err) throw err;

            this.account.password = hash;
        });
    });
};
```

After transpiling:

```
exports.MemberSchema.methods.addAccount = (account) => {
    this.account = new account_1.Account({}, ...account, isActive, true);
};
bcrypt.genSalt(parseInt(process.env.SALT_WORK_FACTOR), function (err, salt) {
    if (err)
        throw err;
    bcrypt.hash(this.account.password, salt, null, function (err, hash) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        this.account.password = hash;
    });
});
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "ES6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "types": ["reflect-metadata"],
    "lib": ["ES6"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "noLib": false,
    "declaration": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

What is causing this issue?  Is there a configuration that needs to change in order to fix this or does it require a change in the typescript file?

Update:

Member.ts:

```
import { Schema, Model } from "mongoose";
import mongoose = require("mongoose");
import {Account, AccountSchema} from "../Account/account";
import {IAccount} from "../Account/iaccount";
import {isNullOrUndefined} from "util";
import {IMemberModel} from "./imembermodel";

export let MemberSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    account: AccountSchema,
    permissions: [{type: Schema.Types.String, enum: ["regularuser", "admin", "owner"]}],
    isActive: Schema.Types.Boolean
});
MemberSchema.pre("save", next => {
    this.isActive = true;

    next();
    return this;
});
MemberSchema.methods.addAccount = (account: IAccount): void => {
    ***this.account = new Account({
        ...account,
        registrationComplete: true
    });***

    bcrypt.genSalt(parseInt(process.env.SALT_WORK_FACTOR), function(err: Error, salt: any){
        if(err) throw err;

        bcrypt.hash(this.account.password, salt, null, function(err: Error, hash: any){
            if(err) throw err;

            this.account.password = hash;
        });
    });
};
MemberSchema.methods.updateAccount = (account: IAccount): void => {
    if (!isNullOrUndefined(account.password)){
        bcrypt.genSalt(parseInt(process.env.SALT_WORK_FACTOR), function(err: Error, salt: any){
            if(err) throw err;

            bcrypt.hash(this.account.password, salt, null, function(err: Error, hash: any){
                if(err) throw err;

                this.account.password = hash;
            });
        });
    }
};

export const Member: Model<IMemberModel> = mongoose.model<IMemberModel>("Member", MemberSchema);
```

Member.js:

```
"use strict";
const mongoose_1 = require("mongoose");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const account_1 = require("../Account/account");
const util_1 = require("util");
exports.MemberSchema = new mongoose_1.Schema({
    account: account_1.AccountSchema,
    permissions: [{ type: mongoose_1.Schema.Types.String, enum: ["regularuser", "admin", "owner"] }],
    isActive: mongoose_1.Schema.Types.Boolean
});
exports.MemberSchema.pre("save", next => {
    this.isActive = true;
    next();
    return this;
});
exports.MemberSchema.methods.addAccount = (account) => {
    this.account = new account_1.Account({}, ...account, registrationComplete, true);
};
;
bcrypt.genSalt(parseInt(process.env.SALT_WORK_FACTOR), function (err, salt) {
    if (err)
        throw err;
    bcrypt.hash(this.account.password, salt, null, function (err, hash) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        this.account.password = hash;
    });
});
;
exports.MemberSchema.methods.updateAccount = (account) => {
    if (!util_1.isNullOrUndefined(account.password)) {
        bcrypt.genSalt(parseInt(process.env.SALT_WORK_FACTOR), function (err, salt) {
            if (err)
                throw err;
            bcrypt.hash(this.account.password, salt, null, function (err, hash) {
                if (err)
                    throw err;
                this.account.password = hash;
            });
        });
    }
};
exports.Member = mongoose.model("Member", exports.MemberSchema);
//# sourceMappingURL=member.js.map
```

Update 2:
The spread operator seems to be the problem.

When I comment out this line:

```
this.account = new Account({
            **//...account,**
            registrationComplete: true
        });
```

It seems to work properly.  If the spread operator is regular es6 syntax, why would that could such a major transpiling issue?

Comment: The transpilation shown is **definitely** not the output of that input code. Post a real self-contained example -- the problem is certainly not in the subset of code you've posted

Comment: I am running the tsc command from the folder containing the tsconfig.json file.  Now I am using webstorm, don't know if that makes a difference, but I can see the dist file generating after tsc completes.  I even deleted everything in dist and it still generates the same code.  Unless it is not picking up the tsconfig.json file, that should be the code generated, as far as I can tell.  Also, I began to notice this when I changed the target to es6 in the tsconfig file.

Comment: You have a syntax error somewhere *above* this code that's causing the problem. Post a **self-contained example that demonstrates the problem**.

Comment: I added part of the code to the file that contains the model that is causing the issue.  Please let me know if more is needed to diagnose.

Comment: The updated version takes a subset of the original file and moved it to another .ts file, and the output is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to compile using an old version of TypeScript that doesn't support the object spread operator (running `tsc -v` will show 2.0 or earlier). Upgrade `tsc` to 2.1 or later.

It's also possible WebStorm is doing a compile-on-save with an old version of TypeScript; read their docs to see how to upgrade the version of TS used to transpile the file.